# argparse code problems

Tags: python, argparse

write a script that takes two optional boolean arguments,"--verbose‚" and ‚"--live", and two required string arguments, "base"and "pattern". Please set up the command line processing using argparse.

```
def main():
    """Put the proper argparse goodness below."""
    pass
```

This is the code I had for the question, but I am totally lost. Any pointers or your pov on the code would be helpful.

```
import argparse 
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description = ("arguments"))
parser = add_argument(--verbose, "base", Type = String)
parser = add_argument(--live, "pattern", Type = String)
parser.argparse('base')argparse('pattern')
print = argparse.ArgumentParer(description = ('arguments')
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want to add are two flags and two arguments, verbose, live, base, and pattern respectively.

Looking at the [argparse documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) we see that you can add boolean switches by specifying an argument with an action of `store_true` or `store_false`: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#action

```
parser.add_argument('--verbose', action='store_true')
```

We also see that we can add a positional argument merely by skipping the flag name:

```
parser.add_argument('base')
```

And that we can specify the required type by using the `type` argument:

```
parser.add_argument('base', type=str)
```

Finally, notice that you should specify your named options first when you define your parser. Everything else gets consumed into your positionl arguments. Note also that positional arguments are, by design, required.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the examples here:

http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html